# How to make sure CSS/JS files are not cached on browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, caching

How do i make sure that for particular ASP.NET page CSS/JS file will not be cached on browser side (each time its loaded from server)?
Anything that can be done using the server side code?

Answer (score 0):

We can use cliend side version no

```
 www.yourwebsite.com/global.js?v=1
```

you can keep change the version no whenever there is change in the javascript file

so the request always gets the new file from the webserver

Comment: to make it even better , maintain the version no in a config file and just increment the no whenever there is change in the css or jss.